# Getting the useState from child functional component and appending it the parent useState array of objects

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a parent component that holds the values of all its child components' information within an array of objects. I'm trying to spawn a new child and keep track of the information within those children in my parent's state as an array of objects. This is where I'm unaware of how to approach this on both fronts; keeping track of the objects within the state and getting the content from the children.

I have a parent component:

```
const Parent: React.FC = () => {
  const [children, setChildren] = React.useState(
    [ 
      {
        id:1, 
        name:'',
        age:0,
      }
    ]
  );
  const getChildName = () => {
     // not sure how to target the new child
  } 

  // Create a new child
  const AddChild = () => {
    let tmpid = children[children.length].id + 1; // not sure if this would work
    setChildren(
      [
        ...children, 
        {
          id:tmpid,
          name:' ',
          age:0,
        }
      ]
    )
  }
  return (
    <button onClick={this.addChild}>Add component</button>
    {
      children.map((child) => (
        <NewChild key={child.id} getChildName={getChildName} getChildAge={getChildAge}/>
      ))
    }
  )
}
```

and then a simple child component:

```
interface IChild {
  name?: string;
  age?: number;
}

type Props = {
  getChildName : void,
  getChildAge : void,
}

const NewChild: React.FC<Props> = (Props) => {
  const [child, setChild] = React.useState<Partial<IChild>>({});

  return (
    <input value={child?.name??''} onChange={e => setChild({...child , child: e.target.value})}/>
    <input value={child?.age??''} onChange={e => setChild({...child , child: parseFloat(e.target.value)})}/>

  )
}
```

Comment: Don't manage the same state in two places. Give the child a callback to notify the parent of updates, which will update the list in the parent and cause the child to be re-rendered with the new value. Also you don't need a Partial of something whose props are already all optional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at how I implemented the getChildName below. It is not tested, but I think it should work. Also take a look at the comments in the code. If you need to implement getChildAge, you can do the same as with getChildName, but return `newChild.age` instead.

```
const Parent: React.FC = () => {
  const [children, setChildren] = React.useState(
    [ 
      {
        id:1, 
        name:'',
        age:0,
      }
    ]
  );
  const getChildName = (id: number) => {
     let newChild = null;

     children.forEach((child) => {
         if (child.id == id) {
             newChild = child;
         }
      }
      return !!newChild ? newChild.name : `No child was found with id ${id}`
  } 

  // Create a new child
  const AddChild = () => {
    /* let tmpid = children[children.length].id + 1; -- this will work. */
    let tmpid = children.length + 1 // This is cleaner, and as long as your id starts on 1,
                                    // this will be the exact same result.
    setChildren(
      [
        ...children, 
        {
          id:tmpid,
          name:' ',
          age:0,
        }
      ]
    )
  }
  return (
    <button onClick={this.addChild}>Add component</button>
    {
      children.map((child) => (
        // You need to add return here.
        return <NewChild key={child.id} getChildName={(child.id) => getChildName(child.id)} getChildAge={getChildAge}/>
      ))
    }
  )
}
```

And like johnrsharpe said, don't manage the same state in two places. You need to give NewChild a callback like this:

```
<NewChild // Inside Render() method of <Parent />
   key={child.id} 
   getChildName={(child.id) => getChildName(child.id)} 
   getChildAge={getChildAge} 
   callback={updateChildren}
/> 

const updateChildren = (inputChild: IChild) => {  // Method of <Parent />
     const newChildren = children.map((child) => {
         if (child.id = inputChild.id) {
             child.name = inputChild.name;
             child.age = inputChild.age;
         }
         return child;
     }

     setChildren([ ...newChildren ]);
}
```

And in NewChild component instead of using setChild state, you pass in the object to a function like

```
const changeChildProperty = (value: any) => {
    // update property of child

    // Pass in the entire child object, and it will be update in parent state through the callback
    props.callback(child);
}
```